# Implementing a live chat system in Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chat

I would like to add a live chat support channel in my website, mainly focused on new users who have specific questions about my services and i´be been thinking about the best way to implement this solution myself. do note that i do not intend to use third party solutions.

What i´ve thought about **retrieving messages:** i can have a form on the page that will activate on user click (like a "start chat" button), once the button is clicked, i will `GET` all messages in the database related to the client's IP address (if it's not a logged in user) through a web service and load it into the DOM. after this, i will have a javascript function that will execute every XX seconds asking whether there are new messages.

to **send messages**: the user will have a textArea with a "send" button that will trigger a `POST` to a web service in order to save their message into the database, on the Support/web admin side, everything will work in a similar fashion but with the option of having several chats at the same time. Also i think I can achieve this by using JQUERY and ajax requests.

Is this a good idea to implement a live chat services? or am I far off from the ideal way of doing this? I have browsed around and all i get is suggestions to use third party service which i definitely do not want to use. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, this is fine, but I would use a websockets and event listeners instead of constant AJAX requests.

Comment: thanks! it is a concept that i´m not all that familiar with so i will be looking into it. Also for whoever has downvoted my question, may I know how is this not an appropriate question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at websockets, especially at the socket.io library, which provides you an event based communication between the clients and the server.
They even have an example how to create a live chat:
http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: I will definitely take a look at that, thanks you very much and i will get back here once i have done some research. Cheers!

Comment: Or a library that uses the best available protocol, e.g. SignalR. There are some SignalR tutorials that use a chat service as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I you want a chat that is not just a "proof of concept", you should go for using [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/), it's the most popular (and maybe the only-one) opensource instant-messaging protocol. There are several implementations in multiple languages and it has proven its robustness.

**Wikipedia :**

> Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP) is a communications protocol for message-oriented middleware based on XML (Extensible Markup Language). It enables the near-real-time exchange of structured yet extensible data between any two or more network entities.

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP)

You could also take a look at IRC, which is quite old but still useful.

Comment: I have never used it in the past, so i'm going to do some research about it, thank you very much!